# ASPX not able to get value of HiddenField, Set by jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to set the value to an ASPX HiddenField with jQuery.

Value is being set, I can inspect and see the value. But when I am fetching it in aspx.cs file the is no value it's returning Null.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_TabID" runat="server" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(MainContent_HiddenField_TabID).val("234w2");
});
```

**file.aspx.ca:**

```
var HidV = HiddenField_TabID.Value; //returns no value

HiddenField hdnCheck = (HiddenField)Page.FindControl("HiddenField_TabID"); //returns no value
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function () { 
   $("#HiddenField_TabID").val("qwerq");
  //$(MainContent_HiddenField_TabID).val("qwerq");
  console.log($("#HiddenField_TabID").val())
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_TabID" runat="server" />
```

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when the form is posted to the server, what data does that request contain?  Is the `name` for the hidden field present in that data, and does it contain a value in that request?

Comment: Yes it does have value.

Comment: Then it sounds like the problem is server-side.  Does anything else in the code-behind ever interact with that value?  Is it being over-written at some point in the page lifecycle (such as in `Page_Load`)?

Comment: thank you, David. Value was being over-written on `Page_Load`. After adding the Postback condition it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways I tend to approach this issue.

My favorite's "lazy" approach?

Just add this to your hiddenfield:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_TabID" 
     runat="server"
     ClientIDMode="static"
 />
```

Now, your jQuery. Note that to select a element by "id", the you ALWAYS use a "#".

So, to get/use the above value, then this:

```
 var myHidden = $("#HiddenField_TabID")

 alert("value = " + myHidden.val())
```

So, to get (or set) the hidden field, use .val()

So, to get, then

```
   $("#HiddenField_tabID").val()
```

And to set, then

```
   $("#HiddenField_tabID").val("Hello world")
```

So, by using ClientIDMode="static", then this stops/prevents the asp.net processor from re-naming the control, and the above 2 examples will work fine.

Of course, if you don't want to add clientIdmode="static" to the hiddenfield control?

Then you can use this format:

```
  var hField = $("#<%= HiddenField_tabID.ClientID %>")
  alert(hField.val())
```

The above is also not too bad. While you have to type more, and it is a bit more "wordy"? It does have and offer intel-sense, so using the above so called "server" expression in the markup is also a great choice here.

So, keep in mind for jQuery:

You use the "#" when selecting a "id" of a element.

You can use ".ClassName" when selecting a element by class.

So, in your examples:

```
$("#HiddenField_TabID").val("qwerq");
```

Well, above could work if you added the clientIDMode="static" to the control on the form.

And since your screen shot shows "Content_" in front? Then that could also be a valid selector (that means you no doubt using a master page).

And say we do NOT use/have "clientIDMode" for the control?

Then this of yours was close, but was missing the "#".

So then this:

```
$("#MainContent_HiddenField_TabID").val("qwerq");
```

However, the <%= %> server side expression?

It will work for ALL cases, and then thus this probably is your best choice until you become more comfortable with the other choices here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.
And I appreciate you explained to me about jQuery selectors.
Actually, I was surprised in aspx selector can work with and without # `$(MainContent_FormChanged).val("True");`

Comment: @TheHunterShergill: That *probably* works because, in global (window) scope, any given `id` *technically* can be referenced as a property on `window`. [Here's a simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/uvw8mhpn/).  So it's not related to ASPX or selectors at all, in this case `MainContent_FormChanged` is literally a property on the `window` object. It's an uncommon practice to rely on it, and I've seen a variety of bugs creep up over the years when people do rely on it. Just as a suggestion, I'd recommend sticking with selectors instead of mixing selectors and `window` properties from `id` values.